# GNU Radio BPSK BER simulation: RRC Pulse Magnitude Normalization

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

A very basic BPSK BER test is being performed (only AWGN is considered). The test is accomplished by using the [gr-mapper OOT](https://oshearesearch.com/index.php/2016/11/02/bit-error-rate-testing-in-gnu-radio/). The first simulation is based on a simple BPSK mapper (1->1, 0->-1) shown below. 
[image: BER without MF]

The results are very close to theoretical BER as shown below
[image: BER]
In the simulation, SNR is specified by varying the noise voltage of the Gaussian noise source. 
Eb = RMS = sqrt((1^2 + 1^2)/2) = 1. Thus, Noise Voltage = sqrt(No) = math.sqrt(1/math.pow(10,SNR/10.0)). More information can be found at this [link](http://monet.postech.ac.kr/class/lab/notes/lab_2.pdf)

I'm now focusing on adding a matched filter accomplished by one RRC filter at transmitter and receiver as shown below. This flowgraph has very poor BER performance.

[image: flowgraph]

Upon close examination of the filtered BPSK signal, the magnitude is no longer 1 (actual value is around 0.15) and hence the value of Eb being used is not accurate. To further verify my conclusion, I used the gnuradio filter design tool. The tool shows that to get a magnitude of 1, the gain has to be set around 7 (at this value, the BER is somehow close to theory).

1. Question: How do I make sure that the pulse magnitude (at t=0) is 1 without manipulating the filter gain to an arbitrary value?

[image: RRC pulse]
 The code for the pulse-shaper (debug_pulseshape_pam_2) is shown below

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include <gnuradio/io_signature.h>
#include "debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl.h"
#include <gnuradio/blocks/char_to_float.h>
#include <gnuradio/digital/map_bb.h>
#include <gnuradio/filter/interp_fir_filter_fff.h>

namespace gr {
     namespace baseband {

debug_pulseshape_pam_2::sptr
debug_pulseshape_pam_2::make(std::vector<float> taps,float sps)
{
  return gnuradio::get_initial_sptr
    (new debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl(taps, sps));
}

/*
 * The private constructor
 */
debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl::debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl(std::vector<float> taps,float sps)
  : gr::hier_block2("debug_pulseshape_pam_2",
          gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(unsigned char)),
          gr::io_signature::make(1, 1, sizeof(float)))
{
  //Initializing the map block
  std::vector<int> map;
  map.push_back(-1);
  map.push_back(1);
  gr::digital::map_bb::sptr mapper(gr::digital::map_bb::make(map));

  //Initializing char_to_float block
  gr::blocks::char_to_float::sptr float_char(gr::blocks::char_to_float::make());

  //Initializing add const block
  //gr::blocks::add_const_ff::sptr const_add(gr::blocks::add_const_ff::make(-0.5));

  //Initializing an interpolating FIR filter
  gr::filter::interp_fir_filter_fff::sptr fir(gr::filter::interp_fir_filter_fff::make(int(sps),taps));

  connect(self(),0,mapper,0);
  connect(mapper,0,float_char,0);
  connect(float_char,0, fir, 0);
  connect(fir, 0,    self(), 0);
}

/*
 * Our virtual destructor.
 */
debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl::~debug_pulseshape_pam_2_impl()
{
}


} /* namespace baseband */
} /* namespace gr */
```

Please do not hesitate to ask for more information if needed.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem finally. Turned out the noise has to be divided by the number of samples per symbol. 
[image]